# Get value from .kv class to .py function

Tags: python, kivy

I have custom class in main.kv file, and with command I can add  to another screen in createRecipe.kv file. But how can I read names.text(from Label), unit.text(from Label) and qtyRe.text(from TextInput) to main.py file?

> screen_manager.get_screen('createRecipe').ingredientforRecipe.add_widget(AddIngToRecipe(names=names, unit=unit))

## main.kv

```
<AddIngToRecipe>
    id: addIngToRecipe
    names: names    
    unit: unit
    MDLabel:
        id: names
        text: str(root.names)
        markup: True
        font_size: '20sp'
        size_hint_x: .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y": .4}
    MDLabel:
        id: unit
        text: str(root.unit)
        markup: True
        font_size: '18sp'
        size_hint_x: .8
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .73, "center_y": .4}
    TextInput:
        id: qtyRe
        hint_text: 'Qty:'
        size_hint: 1, None
        input_filter: 'int'
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        height: 55
        cursor_color: 75/255, 0/255, 130/255, 1
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        multiline: False
```

## createRecipe.kv

```
MDScreen:
    name: 'createRecipe'
    ingredientforRecipe: ingredientforRecipe

    MDFloatLayout:
        id: create_recipe

        ScrollView:
        do_scroll_y: True
        do_scroll_x: False
        size_hint_y: .41
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .55, "y": 0.41}
        bar_width: 0
        GridLayout:

            id: ingredientforRecipe
            cols: 1
            height: self.minimum_height
            row_default_height: 70
            size_hint_y: None
```

## main.py

```
class AddIngToRecipe(FakeRectangularElevationBehavior, FloatLayout, TouchBehavior):
    names = ObjectProperty()
    unit = ObjectProperty()
    def get_from(self):
        names1 = self.ids.qtyRe.text
        print(names1)

class PieceofCake(MDApp, Screen):
    def create_recipe(self, Renames, Recomment):
        self.get_from_addIngToRecipe = AddIngToRecipe()
        self.get_from_addIngToRecipe.get_from()
        names = self.ids.ingredientforRecipe.qtyRe.text
        print(names)
        print(Renames)
        print(Recomment)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names = self.ids.names.text
unit = self.ids.unit.text
qtyRe = self.ids.qtyRe.text
```

Further more, if you want to access values of a widget from a different class from the one you are working with by any chance, you can use:

```
MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.idOfTheClass.ids.idOfTheWidget.valueToGet
```

`MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.idOfTheClass` acts the same as `self` for the targeted class